# Trying to figure out why a sub is causing 27 entries into a mysql database

Tags: mysql, perl

So I have a subroutine in my software that generates a temporary invoice. I really only need the temporary invoice to then add line items to it and publish the invoice for payment. All works well expect the snip of code causes a number of temporary invoices to be generated. I say a number because one time it will be 27 then the next time will be 26.. 25.. 20... and so on.. I don' see anything on here that would loop the sub to cause this. Typically all db calls are done from a separate file and called via a sub but for reference Ive added it into the sub. ** I have removed parts of the code at a time to see if it was causing it, found no issues. I have also tried adding a temp invoice via the sub call from another page without issue. My issue is in this code somewhere!

Comment: Could you clarify if extra temporary invoices are generated and added to the DB or is just one temporary invoice generated, but displayed multiple times on the same page?

Comment: Basically, when that sub is called via 
`if ($q->param('dispatch') eq "create") {
&new_invoice;
}`
link being invoice.cgi?dispatch=create&key=customer id it generates anywhere from 15 - 27 temporary invoices in the db. The first one will contain the proper customer id but everyone after will have a customer id of 0. I've tried to fail the program if a customer id had a empty value or an id of 0 but still created the invoices.

Comment: It looks like new_invoice is being called multiple times, but I'm not sure why. I would try and find out from where all it is being called by using cluck() from Carp to display the stacktrace at the beginning of new_invoice.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all those selects, do just one??

```
$sql = "SELECT fname, lname, ...
    FROM customer
    WHERE customer_id = '$customer_id'";
```

The result is an array of fname, lname, etc.

Comment: While I understand the value of doing that and I will be changing the code to reflect this, I know this isn't whats causing my real issue. Im still trying to diag the issue of 27ish random entries into the db when trying to create just one.

Comment: You have one INSERT in the code; presumably the code is called 27 times?

Answer (score 0):

I ending up figuring out the issue with some help from a user over at reddit. Since Im using mod rewrite apparently items were being called under the link causing the main program to run X extra times and create the random junk entrees. Needless to say it had nothing to do with the script at all!